# Undefined reference to a local class

Tags: c++, qt, qjson

I've just played with qjson library and got "undefined reference" error. This is the code:

```
#include <qjson/qobjecthelper.h>
#include <qjson/serializer.h>

class Person: public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(Gender gender READ gender WRITE setGender)
    Q_ENUMS(Gender)

public:
    Person(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Person();

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    enum Gender{Male, Female};
    Gender gender() const;
    void setGender(Gender gender);

private:
    QString m_name;
    Gender m_gender;

};

int main ()
{

    Person person;

    QJson::Serializer serializer;

    person.setName("Nick");
    person.setGender(Person::Male);
    QVariantMap person_map = QJson::QObjectHelper::qobject2qvariant(&person);

    QByteArray json = serializer.serialize(person_map);
    return 0;
}
```

So, compiler says that `undefined reference to Person::Person` and all other functions in **Person** class. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only *declared* the methods of the class. You also need to *define* (i.e. implement) them. At the moment, how should the compiler know the constructor of `Person` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with the library or object file that implements class Person.

If you have a libqjson.a file on a Unix variant, you need to add -lqjson to your link command line. If you're on Windows with qjson.lib, you need to link with qjson.lib. If you have a .cpp file that implements Person, you need to compile it and link it with your executable.